# Cannot access web server using docker

Tags: docker

I used the following command to run the container :

```
docker run -p 3333:3333 -d maill/node-web-app
```

Here is the result of docker ps :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
f26270107bfa        maill/node-web-app   "npm run dev"       49 seconds ago      Up 46 seconds       0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   musing_fermi
```

However when I try to access webserver on host using localhost:3333  it doesn't work.

I am using windows 10 pro.

`docker logs musing_fermi` shows:

```
DONE Compiled successfully in 3541ms16:04:50 | OPEN localhost:3000
```

Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3333
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "webapp-pst-horizon",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Webapp pour les formations enedis",
  "author": "Léo Coletta",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3333 nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "precommit": "npm run lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.1",
    "@nuxtjs/proxy": "^1.2.4",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "cookie": "^0.3.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "nuxt": "^1.4.1",
    "vuetify": "^1.0.19",
    "webpack": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^4.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^12.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.5.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: What protocol are you trying to use to access it?

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean?

Comment: What does `docker logs musing_fermi` say?

Comment: I get "This page is not working" in chome on the host. I am trying to access it via HTTP protocol using localhost:3000 @johnharris85

Comment: ` DONE  Compiled successfully in 3541ms16:04:50 | OPEN  http://localhost:3000` @zero298

Comment: Please add your `Dockerfile` and maybe your `package.json` then, I don't think it's actually running your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you have in the question so far, and that you have `OPEN localhost:3000` coming from your container logs, I'd guess your application is listening on `localhost`. This is != `localhost` outside the container. You need to configure your application to listen on `0.0.0.0` inside the container.

Comment: When I changed the IP to 0.0.0.0, the web server is still indicating it is running on localhost (I updated my package.json to follow along zero298 anwser.

Comment: Ok now it work and I don't know what I changed to make it work but thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To go along with [johnharris85's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51140365/691711), add the following to your `package.json`:

From [nuxt documentation on "How to edit HOST and PORT?"](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port/)

> You can configure the PORT with 3 different ways:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. ...
> 3. Via a nuxt config in the package.json:
>
> Inside your package.json:
>
> ```
> "config": {
>  "nuxt": {
>    "host": "0.0.0.0",
>    "port": "3333"
>  }
> },
> "scripts": {
>  "dev": "nuxt"
> }
> ```

Comment: Yes I just saw, however when I added the 0.0.0.0 to the host (I used methods 2 with cross-env), docker logs said the same thing : ` OPEN  http://localhost:3333 `